# aligning round button next to select component

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have written this code that pulls json from backend api and populate select component in vue. I want to add a reload button right next to the select component,

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <title>Test page app</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
   <style>

   .round-button {
       width:3%; // controls the size of button
   }
   .round-button-circle {
      width: 100%;
      height:0;
      padding-bottom: 100%;
      border-radius: 50%;
      line-height:50px;
      border:1px solid #cfdcec;
      overflow:hidden;
      background: #4679BD;
      box-shadow: 0 0 5px gray;
   }
   .round-button-circle:hover {
      background:#30588e;
   }

   .round-button img {
      display: block;
      width: 90%; // control image size
      padding: 24%; // control image alignment
      padding-right: 50%;
      height: auto;
   }

   </style>

   <script src="static/vendor/vue.js"></script>
   <script src="static/vendor/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="select">
   <form>
<select v-model="selected" v-on:change.once="executeLoader('tests', $event)"># v-bind:disabled="isRunning">
<option disabled selected>Please Select One</option>
   <option></option>
<option v-for="n in projects" :value="n">
{{n.id}} : {{ n.name }}
</option>
</select>
      <div class="round-button">
         <div class="round-button-circle">
      <a href="#" class="round-button">
<img src="images/leftarrow.png" alt="Reload" title="Reload" />
</a></div>
         </div>
<h3>Selected: {{ selected.name }} </h3>
      </form>

</div>

<script>
new Vue({
   el: "#select",
   data: {
      projects: [],
      selected: "Please Select One",
      isRunning: false
   },
   methods : {
      executeLoader: function(t, event){

      alert('Query "'+ this.selected.name +
         '" Dropdown: "' + t + '"');

         if (!this.selected){
            console.log("did not submitted");
         } else {
            this.isRunning = true;
            }
         }
      },
   mounted() {
   axios.get("projects.json")
   //axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5050/api/images?filter=placeholder")
   .then(response => {
         this.projects = response.data.projects
      })
   }
});
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

but the image button I have created is going to next line instead of showing up right next to div .

Comment: pls provide a complete example. especially the HTML

Comment: I have updated the html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your css:

```
.round-button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

New version:

```
.round-button {
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz, I just added new solution. Please try it.

Comment: `display: inline-block;` worked with `vertical-align:middle;`

Comment: Nice catch bro. Hope it helps.

Comment: I also added `width:15px` ; which in my post I had `3%` becuase I want size to be fixed matching the size of dropdown's height